# How to iterate through an array stored in Local Storage JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

In this application I am getting this information from users in an HTML form: `var orderName, trackingNumber, price` the user is updating these dynamically. Then I'm storing them in an array, converting it to json format, and keeping the orderName variable (which the user gave earlier) as the local storage key,

```
    var myArray = [];
    myArray.push(orderName, trackingNumber,price);

    var JsonOrder = JSON.stringify(myArray );
    localStorage.setItem(orderName,JsonOrder );
```

Now I want to display all the orders and their information. One page with all the orders listed, and the orderName should be a HYPERLINK that takes user to a page with information on just that order.

Here is what I'm doing to loop through the array:

```
 var savedOrders = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('orderName'));
 var orderName;
 var trackingNumber;
 var price;


 for (var key in savedOrders ) {

  orderName  = savedOrders[key][0];
  trackingNumber = savedOrders[key][1];
  price = savedOrders[key][2];


 }
```

This isn't working?

Comment: `.0` isn't valid syntax. You need to use the bracket notation `[0]` instead.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: there are many, many, many questions on Stack Overflow regarding how to iterate over an array in Javascript.  which of them did you try and why did they not solve your specific problem?

Comment: I tried [0] not working either its giving me an "undefined"

Comment: My solution for iterating through an array saved in local storage is not working hence the purpose of asking and posting code

Comment: for example doing savedOrders[key][1] gives me : eeundefinede instead of the actual array value that is stored in that key of the local storage

Comment: My question wasn't "does your code work?".  it obviously doesn't or else we wouldn't be here.  My question was "once you noticed that your code didn't work, what research did you do and what is different about your particular problem such that zero existing Stack Overflow results could solve it?".

Comment: My main problem is that iterating through the loop only returns the array keyname that is stored. I haven't found a solution here for retrieving the array values within each key.Most of the local storage questions here are just for keynames haven't found one for a question of my nature that works.

Answer (score 0):

simply do

```
let JsonOrder = JSON.stringify( [orderName, trackingNumber, price] );
localStorage.setItem('someName',JsonOrder );

//---
let orderName, trackingNumber, price;
[orderName, trackingNumber, price] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('someName'));
```

Comment: Can you please explain me the logic of how this would work?

Comment: @ckaepie  the Destructuring assignment ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: I meant the line ```let JsonOrder = JSON.stringify( [orderName, trackingNumber, price] );``` this is an array right don't I need to declare it before?

Comment: @ckaepie  it create a temporary array  inside the JSON.stringify method, it's the same way when you use a compute (or whatever) as argument for any function, like `myFunct(  X + 7 );` ...

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here:

```
// Get the existing data
var existing = localStorage.getItem('myFavoriteSandwich');

// If no existing data, create an array
// Otherwise, convert the localStorage string to an array
existing = existing ? existing.split(',') : [];

// Add new data to localStorage Array
existing.push('tuna');

// Save back to localStorage
localStorage.setItem('myFavoriteSandwich', existing.toString());
```

from https://gomakethings.com/how-to-update-localstorage-with-vanilla-javascript/

I think there is a better way then to use split since what if the user enters a [] or , as their input?But so far this works just not a good method.